# Create borders for a specific range in Excel using run vbscript in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to run a VBscript through Power Automate Desktop to add borders to a certain range in an Excel Worksheet. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am getting an error saying Type Mismatch: Range.

I have attached the code here for reference. I am initializing the variable - Excel File with the file path

```
Dim Excel
Dim ExcelDoc
'Opens the Excel file
    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelDoc = Excel.Workbooks.open("%ExcelFile%"
Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(“A1:C3")

    With myRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Colorindex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

'Closes the Excel file
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

Excel.Application.Quit
```

Comment: Check the quote here ... `Set myRange = Range(“A1:C3")` ... the one next the left of `A1` looks dodgearama.  That's the first thing, also, where's the closing bracket next to `%ExcelFile%`?  I'd suggest you need to maybe be explicit regarding the worksheet you want to get the range for as well.  That's my suggestion.

Comment: Please try `Run Excel Macro` (VBA code) with PA desktop. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Excel actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/excel#runmacro?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)